# How to set different Passport JS Bearer strategy per endpoint and REST methods?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm using `BearerStrategy` and I'm trying to set different strategy per endpoint or method, in the same router.

I've looked over the documentation and i haven't seen any refer to this situation, besides creating a new router.

this is what i got:

```
const router = express.Router()

passport.use(new BearerStrategy(
  { passReqToCallback: true },
  async function (req, token, done) {
      if (token) { 
      // business logic 
      }
   }));

router.post("/",
 passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false, passReqToCallback: true, failWithError: true },
  function (req, res, next) { // handle success 
},
  function (err, req, res, next) { // handle failure 
});

router.get("/",
 passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false, passReqToCallback: true, failWithError: true },
  function (req, res, next) { // handle success 
},
  function (err, req, res, next) { // handle failure 
});

router.get("/:username",
 passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false, passReqToCallback: true, failWithError: true },
  function (req, res, next) { // handle success 
},
  function (err, req, res, next) { // handle failure 
});
```

and i seek for how to implement different business logic per endpoint. one for the `GET /`, other for  `GET /:username` and for `POST /` api

[in this tutorial](https://medium.com/@bmshamsnahid/node-js-authentication-using-passport-js-78386be1f518) i saw this:

```
    passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({ ... })
    passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({ ... })

    router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
        successRedirect : '/auth/profile',
        failureRedirect : 'auth/signup'
    }));

    router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
        successRedirect : '/auth/profile',
        failureRedirect : 'auth/login'
    }));
```

but wasn't able to do the same with the `BearerStrategy`.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same as in the tutorial. Set some label for the strategy, and then refer to it.

```
passport.use('GET-strategy', new BearerStrategy(
  { passReqToCallback: true },
  async function (req, token, done) {
      if (token) { 
      // business logic 
      }
   }));


passport.use('POST-strategy', new BearerStrategy(
  { passReqToCallback: true },
  async function (req, token, done) {
      if (token) { 
      // business logic 
      }
   }));
```

and then:

```
router.get("/",
 passport.authenticate('GET-strategy', { session: false, passReqToCallback: true, failWithError: true }),
  function (req, res, next) { // handle success 
},
  function (err, req, res, next) { // handle failure 
});

router.post("/",
 passport.authenticate('POST-strategy', { session: false, passReqToCallback: true, failWithError: true }),
  function (req, res, next) { // handle success 
},
  function (err, req, res, next) { // handle failure 
});
```

Comment: The parentheses in your second code block don't match up.